# Search through list of tuples and display results

Tags: python, list, search, tuples

I have a list of tuples and I am trying to search through the list and display all of the results containing the search term. So far I have this:

```
holidays = []
holidays.append((1001,"Tenerife","Spain",2, 7, 80))
holidays.append((1002,"Cancun","Mexico",4, 14, 120))
holidays.append((1003,"Pairs","France",2, 3, 75))
holidays.append((1004,"Salzburg","Austria",3, 10, 90))
holidays.append((1004,"Madrid","Spain",3, 10, 90))enter code here
```

and:

```
search = input("Please enter a destination city or country to display all matching results: ")
    for item in holidays:
        if search in item:
           print ()
           print ("Here are all the results containing the word", search)
           print ()
           print ("Package ID:", item[0],":", item[1], "-", item[2],":",item[3], "person(s)",
           "for",  item[4], "nights costing" , "£" + str(item[5]), "pp/night")
           print ()
           menu = input("Press any key to return to the main menu:")
```

But if I search for Spain, it will only display the first result containing the word Spain and not all of them. Am I right in thinking that it should display all of the results containg the search term as it is inside a for loop?

Comment: That `input` will wait for you to press enter before continuing the loop after the first found result... I suspect you want that dedented

Comment: The input does display more than one, just that you have an input inside your for loop

Answer (score 0):

Just put the two first print and the second input outside the loop:

```
holidays = []
holidays.append((1001, "Tenerife", "Spain", 2, 7, 80))
holidays.append((1002, "Cancun", "Mexico", 4, 14, 120))
holidays.append((1003, "Pairs", "France", 2, 3, 75))
holidays.append((1004, "Salzburg", "Austria", 3, 10, 90))
holidays.append((1004, "Madrid", "Spain", 3, 10, 90))

search = input("Please enter a destination city or country to display all matching results: ")
print()
print("Here are all the results containing the word", search)
for item in holidays:
    if search in item:
        print()
        print("Package ID:", item[0], ":", item[1], "-", item[2], ":", item[3], "person(s)", "for",  item[4], "nights costing", "£" + str(item[5]), "pp/night")
menu = input("Press any key to return to the main menu:")
```

Comment: This will make the program stop for every iteration in holidays.

Comment: In my example I didn't put the menu = input line outside the loop but outside the if statement, anyway now work

Comment: well, now you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Just do like this

```
print ()
print ("Here are all the results containing the word", search)
print ()
for item in holidays:
    if search in item:
        print ("Package ID:", item[0],":", item[1], "-", item[2],":",item[3], "person(s)",
        "for",  item[4], "nights costing" , "£" + str(item[5]), "pp/night")
        print ()
menu = input("Press any key to return to the main menu:")
```

And the input will prompt when you are done searching in the loop.